# Calculating different rated power from the rated parameters for a delta AC motor

Tags: motor, ac

A delta connected motor in the following link:
http://www.vanbodegraven.nl/en/products/ac-motors/asea-mbg-200-m-60-6/

has rated current 47A, voltage 380V

Here is the rated values. Cos(fi) = 0.8 on the label.

So the power I calculate is = sqrt(3)*380*47*cos(fi) = 24747 is around 25kw

But AS YOU SEE the label stated rated power 22kw

Why my calculation does not match the rated power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rated power of a motor is the **mechanical output power**. That is, speed × torque.

The input power to a motor is the **electrical input power**. That is, line-line voltage × current × √3.

**The motor is not 100% efficient**. Some energy is lost in the conversion between electrical power and mechanical power.

Your 'missing' 3kW represents the **motor's losses**, including copper (resistive) loss, iron loss, friction, drag, spinning the integrated cooling fan (if any), etc.